# Pixel modifications does not cover whole image

Tags: c++, ios, opencv, image-processing, pixel

I've been doing some work with opencv and image processing. Every once in a while i've run into the situation where when I try to do some pixel modifications manually like here:

```
cv::Mat newImg = cv::Mat::zeros(img.size(), img.type());

    for( int y = 0; y < img.rows; y++ )
    {
        for( int x = 0; x < img.cols; x++ )
        {
            cv::Vec3b intensity = img.at<cv::Vec3b>(y, x);
            r = intensity.val[0];
            g = intensity.val[1];
            b = intensity.val[2];

            intensity.val[0] = r - (r * modify - r);
            intensity.val[1] = g - (g * modify - g);
            intensity.val[2] = b - (b * modify - b);

            newImg.at<cv::Vec3b>(y, x) = intensity;
        }
    }
```

This produces a new image that has a black box like so

[image]

Now i just dont understand why the for loops do not cover the whole photo, ive managed to fix this before but by pure luck and still do not understand why and where this problem comes from.

So my question in short is: How do i remove this black box from my images?

Thanks

Comment: I think the black region happens because you switched rows/columns in your loop.

Comment: Seems very likely, given that the height of the non-black region is same as the width. Try changing x and y.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most common cause of this issue is that you are accessing the image with the wrong element type. You use `.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x)` for pixel access. This assumes that the image has only BGR channels. Your image data is probably in BGRA format, especially since this is iOS's native image format.

To remedy your problem, change all instances of `cv::Vec3b` with `cv::Vec4b`, and the code should work correctly.

Comment: Possibly an alpha channel? 480/640 = 3/4: you seem to be on to something here

Comment: Awesome! That seems have done the trick, question though: is it safe to say that `intensity.val[3]` would contain the Alpha channel data for that pixel?

Comment: That is exactly the case.

Comment: question then, i have seen some code where the use `img.at<uchar>` to get and set pixel data, is that for one channel images?

Comment: Yes. The type parameter to `.at<>()` must match the data type of the `Mat` being accessed. Multi-channel images are accessed with `cv::Vec`.